# convert from list to dataframe in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I need to dig out similar dataframes from a list and put them into a dataframe. I´ve created a toy example:

```
nn <- list()
h <- data.frame(a = c(5,6), j = c(8,1), g = c("d","o"))
rnz <- c("test1","test2")
o <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), j = c(6,4), g = c("r","u"))
rownames(h) <- rnz
rownames(o) <- rnz
i <- 1:4
nn$set1 <- list(num = i, df = h)
nn$set2 <- list(num = i / 2, df = o)
```

Now I´d like to extract the list into the following tidy format

```
       var a j
set1 test1 5 8
set1 test2 6 1
set2 test1 1 6
set2 test2 2 4
```

But - when I do

```
df <- lapply(nn, function(x) x$df[ , c(1,2)])
df2 <- lapply(df, function(x) tibble::rownames_to_column(x, "var"))

df3 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df2, function(c) as.data.frame(c, row.names = NULL)))
```

I get:

```
         var a j
set1.1 test1 5 8
set1.2 test2 6 1
set2.1 test1 1 6
set2.2 test2 2 4
```

How can I remove remove the .1,.2 etc in the rowcolumn? Is there a neater way of doing this?

Comment: That is the easiest way to do it though. You have your rownames, just convert them into column names. Then you want to remove .1 .2 with `gsub(pattern = '[.][0-9]', replacement ='', df3$collumnThatUsedToBeRownames)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rbindlist` with the `idcol` argument

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(nn, function(x) transform( x$df[1:2], 
         var = row.names(x$df))), idcol = "name")
#    name a j   var
#1: set1 5 8 test1
#2: set1 6 1 test2
#3: set2 1 6 test1
#4: set2 2 4 test2
```

Comment: For the first time I actually found data.table jargon easier to comprehend than hadley-jargon. Thx.

Answer (score 8):

`dplyr::bind_rows` has a `.id` parameter to coerce element names to a column. `purrr::map_df` wraps it, including the `.id` parameter, so you can convert directly from `nn`:

```
library(purrr)

       # extract data.frame elements
nn %>% map('df') %>% 
    # add rownames to each data.frame; coerce result to data.frame with element names as column
    map_df(tibble::rownames_to_column, 'var', .id = 'name')

##   name   var a j g
## 1 set1 test1 5 8 d
## 2 set1 test2 6 1 o
## 3 set2 test1 1 6 r
## 4 set2 test2 2 4 u
```

Comment: NIce--Have you come across any vignettes or examples using Purrr? The documentation in the package is quite terse.

Comment: The release notes ([0.1](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/09/29/purrr-0-1-0/), [0.2](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/01/06/purrr-0-2-0/)) are a good starting point. One frequent usage is [tidying models](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/01/06/purrr-0-2-0/). At base, though, it's a simple paradigm: `map` is like `lapply` (with some shortcuts built-in), and the suffixes specify how to simplify the result (like `vapply`, but less annoying), so `map_df` applies a function and then simplifies to a data.frame.

Comment: thx-this lecture by Hadley was also good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg#t=4171.14477. Furthermore, http://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html is very helpful.

Comment: Oops, the video was what the third link in my previous comment was supposed to go to. I didn't realize he'd added purrr to r4ds; that's probably the best source to get started.